# 502 Bad Gateway instead of ad banners

Tags: support, status-completed, advertising, 500-server-error

I've seen a few times that the ads/banners are getting a 502 error:

> 502 Bad Gateway - nginx/1.11.6
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

[image: 502 Bad Gateway - nginx/1.11.6, Android, Stack Exchange]

It works after refresh, so it's difficult to reproduce the issue in a consistent way.

To clarify, I'm not using any proxy or VPN, and I'm not using any ad blocker. The ads are displayed properly for 99% of time.

Related: [Ad Broken on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350083/55075)

Comment: I think I have seen that nginx one during my testing [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350083/ad-broken-on-stack-overflow) as well.

Comment: The same issue has cropped up on the stackoverflow meta [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346130/advertisement-502-bad-gateway-error/346133#346133). __Tl;dr:__ it's an issue with the ads themselves, and probably sporadic, rather than something to do with stack exchange.

Comment: @kenorb still seeing this? i haven't seen it for a while but want to confirm before answering to that end.

Comment: @stevvve Not since then.

Comment: @kenorb Okay. I'll respond and label this as [status:resolved] for now, but if you (or anyone else) sees it again, please open things up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making some adjustments to internal promotion ads and their priorities-- which I suspected were related (if not the direct cause of the issue)-- we're no longer seeing the 502 Bad Gateway error.

If you or anyone else sees it return, feel free to let us know here.

Thank you for bringing this to our attention!